# How can I dispose Excel COM object on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, comobject

I have a ASP.NET app on IIS . In this application I use Excel COM Object :

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I use this objects:

```
        public Excel.Application ExlApp;
        //
        public Excel.Workbook ExlWb;
        //
        public Excel.Worksheet ExlWs;
```

And destroy them like this:

```
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExlWs);



        ExlWb.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExlWb);

        ExlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(ExlApp);
```

So, it works normal on Visual Studio 2008.
BUT! When I start this application only on IIS, the Excel process could not be destroy!
HELP!

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues in the past with excel processes sticking around after calling .Quit() as well.  The solution I hacked my way into was finding the running process and killing it.  This may not be optimal, but I though I would share my experience.

Comment: I agree it isn't ideal and probably isn't the final answer, but I could never get the interop excel shutdown to behave correctly.  I was also using Office 2003 at the time, and the tools have come a long way since then.

Comment: "using Automation from Windows Service (IIS and ASP.NET for example) is NOT supported by MS " so...it seems that killing proceseas is the one way to stop EXCEL.